# cftime.DatetimeNoLeap object fails to convert with pandas.to_datetime()

Tags: pandas, time, python-xarray

I'm using xarray to read in multiple climate model data and since upgrading python my code has now stopped working.

It's falling over because some of the model data has a different calendar:

```
In [15]: ds.coords['time'].values[0]
Out[15]: cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(1861, 1, 16, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16)
```

which means pandas.to_datetime() fails:

```
pd.to_datetime(ds.coords['time'].values[0])
TypeError: <type 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The accepted answer does indeed successfully convert the time, but as far as I can tell, I still cannot slice on the transformed times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been recent changes in xaray to better support non-standard calendars. There is a full section in the xarray documentation describing these changes and how to restore previous behavior ([link to docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#non-standard-calendars-and-dates-outside-the-timestamp-valid-range)).

I think in your case, if you want to convert your time values to standard full Pandas Datetimes, you can simply use the `to_datetimeindex()` method:

```
ds.indexes['time'].to_datetimeindex()
```